# How to set Custom marker image using charts library

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Any one found solution for custom marker Image using charts library. i want to add custom marker like in the bellow picture , anyone can help me. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used custom image in one of my graph

Please check below code to add marker with custom image in it.

```
let marker = BalloonMarker(color: .clear,
                               font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold),
                               textColor: .black,
                               insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2))

marker.chartView = self
marker.image = UIImage.init(named: "dialog_popup")
marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width:42,height:42)
self.marker = marker
self.drawMarkers = true
```

By adding this code marker is enabled in your chart.

Now do one more change in `BalloonMarker` class:

add below line in `draw()` method of above class:

```
image!.draw(in: rect)
```

Hope this will helps!

Comment: Hi, have you do that highliteghted line height up to data point.if you did that can you help me.

Comment: And BalloonMarker is a subclass of what?